# Endless compilations when SourceCodePro is loaded, target PDF absent but aux file present

Tags: luatex, fontspec, latexmk, sourcecodepro

For some time now I witnessed latexmk compiling my documents 5 times in a row. I thought that was because I was doing very complicated things with beamer.

But consider the following code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro}
\begin{document}
gh
\end{document}
```

Compile it with `latexmk -pdflua test.tex`. It compiles one time and produces a nice PDF file.

Now delete the PDF file and run the same command : latexmk compiles 5 times before aborting because `'lualatex' needed too many passes`. (note : in my normal setup, I compile in a subdirectory and move the resulting PDF back, this is why this situation arises ; if the target PDF remains present, latexmk will simply not start compilation).

Now try without PDF and without .aux file : compiles one time.

Try without PDF, with .aux but without all other generated files : compiles endlessly.

What is the content of this mischievous .aux file ? This :

```
\relax
```

Finally, remove the `\setmonofont{Source Code Pro}` in the source and experiment again : everything works fine. Indeed, latexmk says that

```
Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      '/opt/yann/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/sourcecodepro-boldit.luc'
      '/opt/yann/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/sourcecodepro-regular.luc'
```

These file are really modified during compilation.

Update after @DG comment : running `luaotfload-tool --cache=erase` allows for one normal compilation, but the problem arises again afterwards.

The log file is identical in all cases :

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018)  (format=lualatex 2019.2.12)  18 FEB 2019 10:15
 restricted system commands enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / initializatio
n
Lua module: lualibs 2019-01-28 2.63 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2019-01-28 2.63 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / logging
Lua module: luaotfload-parsers 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / filelist
Lua module: luaotfload-configuration 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / conf
ig file reader
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /opt/yann/texlive/2018/texmf-var/lua
tex-cache/generic/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2019-01-28.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “/opt/yann/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontlo
ader-2019-01-28.lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 3
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.107”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Lua module: luaotfload-loaders 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / callback h
andling
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-database 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / database
Lua module: luaotfload-colors 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 4
Lua module: luaotfload-resolvers 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / resolver
s
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /opt/yann/texlive/2018/texmf-var/lua
tex-cache/generic/names.
Lua module: luaotfload-features 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / features
Lua module: luaotfload-letterspace 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-auxiliary 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / auxiliar
y functions
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.064 seconds
(/opt/yann/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/yann/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /opt/yann/texlive/2018/texmf-v
ar/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/opt/yann/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/opt/yann/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/opt/yann/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2019-02-15 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/opt/yann/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2019-02-15 L3 programming layer (code)
\ucharcat@table=\catcodetable5
\c_max_int=\count88
\l_tmpa_int=\count89
\l_tmpb_int=\count90
\g_tmpa_int=\count91
\g_tmpb_int=\count92
\g__kernel_prg_map_int=\count93
\c_log_iow=\count94
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count95
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count96
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count97
\l__iow_indent_int=\count98
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count99
\l__intarray_loop_int=\count100
\c__intarray_sp_dim=\dimen109
\g__intarray_font_int=\count101
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count102
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count109
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count110
\g__fp_array_int=\count111
\l__fp_array_loop_int=\count112
\l__sort_length_int=\count113
\l__sort_min_int=\count114
\l__sort_top_int=\count115
\l__sort_max_int=\count116
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count117
\l__sort_block_int=\count118
\l__sort_begin_int=\count119
\l__sort_end_int=\count120
\l__sort_A_int=\count121
\l__sort_B_int=\count122
\l__sort_C_int=\count123
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count124
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count125
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count126
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count127
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count128
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count129
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count130
\l__regex_balance_int=\count131
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count132
\l__regex_mode_int=\count133
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count134
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count135
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count136
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count137
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count138
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count139
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count140
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count141
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count142
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count143
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count144
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count145
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count146
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count147
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count148
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count149
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count150
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count151
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count152
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count153
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count154
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count155
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count156
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count157
\l__regex_step_int=\count158
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count159
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count160
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count161
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count162
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count163
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count164
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count165
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count166
\c_empty_box=\box27
\l_tmpa_box=\box28
\l_tmpb_box=\box29
\g_tmpa_box=\box30
\g_tmpb_box=\box31
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen110
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen111
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen112
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen113
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen114
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen115
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen116
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen117
\l__box_internal_box=\box32
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box33
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen118
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen119
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen120
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen121
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen122
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen123
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen124
\c_empty_coffin=\box34
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box35
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box36
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box37
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box38
\g_tmpa_coffin=\box39
\g_tmpb_coffin=\box40
\c__coffin_empty_coffin=\box41
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box42
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box43
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box44
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen125
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen126
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen127
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen133
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen134
\l__seq_internal_a_int=\count167
\l__seq_internal_b_int=\count168
)
(/opt/yann/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def
File: l3pdfmode.def 2019-02-15 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
\l__driver_color_stack_int=\count169
))
Package: xparse 2018-10-17 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count170
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count171
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count172
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count173
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count174
)
Package: fontspec 2019/02/12 v2.7b Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Lua module: fontspec 2019/02/12 2.7b Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
(/opt/yann/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
Package: fontspec-luatex 2019/02/12 v2.7b Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count175
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count176
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count177
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count178
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count179
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count180
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count181
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count182
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count183
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count184
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count185
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen135
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen136
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen137

(/opt/yann/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package

(/opt/yann/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def
File: tuenc.def 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding TU on input line 82.
))
(/opt/yann/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 3776.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 3781.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 3786.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 3791.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 3821.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 3846.
))
luaotfload | cache : Lookup cache loaded from /opt/yann/texlive/2018/texmf-var/l
uatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc.
luaotfload | aux : font no 29 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script latn
 with language dflt
luaotfload | aux : no font with id 29
luaotfload | aux : font no 34 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script latn
 with language dflt
luaotfload | aux : no font with id 34
luaotfload | aux : font no 35 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script latn
 with language dflt
luaotfload | aux : no font with id 35
luaotfload | aux : font no 36 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script latn
 with language dflt
luaotfload | aux : no font with id 36

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'SourceCodePro(0)' created for font 'Source
(fontspec)             Code Pro' with options
(fontspec)             [WordSpace={1,0,0},HyphenChar=None,PunctuationSpace=WordS
pace].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"SourceCodePro:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font
(fontspec)             =0\fontdimen 3\font \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen
(fontspec)             4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"SourceCodePro/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;"

(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font
(fontspec)             =0\fontdimen 3\font \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen
(fontspec)             4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"SourceCodePro/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;"

(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font
(fontspec)             =0\fontdimen 3\font \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen
(fontspec)             4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (bx/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"SourceCodePro/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;
"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font
(fontspec)             =0\fontdimen 3\font \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen
(fontspec)             4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 

LaTeX Info: Redefining \ttfamily on input line 4.

(./test.aux)
\openout1 = test.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.

Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/lmr/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/bx/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/SourceCodePro(0)/m/n on input line 4
.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/bx/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/lmr/bx/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/bx/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/SourceCodePro(0)/bx/n on input line 
4.
 [1

{/opt/yann/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.
aux))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 11516 strings out of 494383
 100000,383344 words of node,token memory allocated
 414 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 5 attribute, 49 glue_spec,
 5 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:15,3:3,4:2,5:21,6:1,7:15,8:1,9:6
 15661 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 36 fonts using 7879519 bytes
 47i,4n,67p,343b,446s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,100000s
</home/yann/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 2755 bytes).

PDF statistics: 15 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 8 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

**WTF ?**

lualatex is Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018). latexmk is Version 4.61. OS is KUbuntu 18.04.

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue (same versions of lualatex and latexmk). Have you changed your `latexmkrc` or added a local one? What does the log say?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the cache? `$ luaotfload-tool --cache=erase`
and then `$ texhash`

Comment: Clearing the cache does allow for a "normal" compilation once, but if I try a second time it loops again.

Comment: I do not get any issues on a full up to date TL18. I do have recorder disabled by default, so I'm running `latexmk` with the `-norc` option. Mine does not loop. Ifs your TL18 up to date (including the lualatex stuff).

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What OS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, [latexmk can be instructed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/348361/103608) to not take care of changing .luc files by adding the following to `~/.latexmkrc`

```
$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'luc'}='^';
```

This is a workaround rather than a real solution because it remains that .luc files are being touched by lualatex seemingly for no reason.

Comment: Like other commenters to the question, I cannot reproduce this.  I'm also using texlive 2018 with luatex 1.07.0, but on OS-X. Then I looked at  the .luc files mentioned in the question. They all have a timestamp. That suggests that lualatex is recreating those files on every run. Then the timestamp changes, so latexmk sees a file with changed content and deduces that another run of lualatex is needed. Perhaps there's something unusual in the OP's setup, e.g., to cause it to delete the files after every run?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this. It seems there is something with lualatex ; I opened an issue there https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/425

Comment: The `lualatex/luaotfload` repo is no longer maintained. Please report the issue at https://github.com/u-fischer/luaotfload

Comment: Ah, good to know ! I saw that khaledhosny/luaotfload was archived but lualatex/luaotfload is not…