# Avoid latexmk rerun forced by new timestamp of lualatex cache

Tags: luatex, latexmk

I am trying to setup a GitLab project with CI such that the PDF artifacts would be built in the job only when the source tex files changed. I've already resolved the problem with modification date of the tex files by using `git-restore-mtime`. However, `latexmk` still runs `lualatex` even when the source files are older than the cached PDFs. The reason is as follows:

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 7 Jan. 2023. Version 4.79.
Latexmk: applying rule 'lualatex'...
Rule 'lualatex':  Reasons for rerun
Changed files or newly in use/created:
  /usr/share/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc
Category 'changed_user':
  /usr/share/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc
```

When I print out the modification timestamp of `luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc`, it is the current time. So it seems that this modification timestamp is set once the Docker container is created. I do run `luaotfload-tool --update` when the Docker image is created, but it does not help.

Is there any way how to solve the described problem. That is, to setup `latexmk` together with `lualatex` such that it would not force build rerun in my case, when the tex sources are not newer than cached PDFs?

**UPDATE**

I additionally put the following line into `latexmkrc` (as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/348361/4500)), but for some reason, it didn't stop rerunning:

```
$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'luc'}='^';
```

Comment: In such situations, the time stamps of the files are irrelevant to latexmk, only their contents.  So there's absolutely no need to be concerned with setting or not setting the timestamps of the files in question.  The message you see could also arise if (a) for some reason the file `/usr/share/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc` was listed as a source file on the previous invocation of latexmk on the source file, but didn't exist.  (b) It now exists, so from latexmk's point of view it's a new file.

Comment: @JohnCollins Thanks for the explanation. However, that file definitely existed even prior to `latexmk` call. I verify that by checking this file right after the Docker container is created and before `latexmk` is called. Also, both in the Docker image and container, the file has the same owner (root). So the `changed_user` reason is also weird.

Comment: What latexmk means by a "changed_user" file is that the changed file is one that is comes into the compilation from outside the compilation.  That is in contrast to one that is generated one every run by *latex or one of the other programs that latexmk runs (e.g., an .aux file).  So a file listed as changed_user could be an ordinary source file like a .tex file.  But it could also be one of the files that are part of the TeX distribution.  Cache files are special cases: They are only occasionally generated during a run.

Comment: Generally, my experience is that latexmk often knows better when to run something than I do.  So unless I am particularly concerned in particular cases, I just trust latexmk to do something suitable. If there's a one-time extra run, I don't get bothered.  In your case, the big complication is the creation of a Docker image; all kinds of subtlety can happen. To sort out the reason for the apparently superfluous run would need a detailed examination of the work flow, and examination of the contents of the .fdb_latexmk file where latexmk saves dependence information.

Comment: @JohnCollins Yes, the problem is caused by this specific scenario with Docker containers creation. It's just weird that the solution with `hash_calc_ignore_pattern` does not work. Anyway, I was able to create a workaround by letting `make` decide whether the recompilation is required for a specific source tex (by comparing timestamps with pdfs) and then running `latexmk` only for the required sources.